# Rhomobile direct data exchange with desktop/laptop

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

We are going to be building a mobile application that will need to sync with a laptop.  This may be over USB, Bluetooth, etc.  Is it possible to do this with Rhomobile without a sync server?  We need to sync between the device and laptop in environments with no internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Bluetooth stack through RhoMobile to connect to another Bluetooth enabled device. However, there are some limitations of the various platforms which are outlined in the attached link.

[RhoMobile Bluetooth Capabilities](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#bluetooth)